# Determining weight to within 0.1mg?

Tags: experimental-chemistry

For a recent laboratory session we were asked to weight a 20mL beaker three times on an analytical scale. Each time, we were asked to determine the weight to within +/- 0.1mg. I am just a little confused about what this means as I have never been asked to round this way.
The three values are: 13.5448g, 13.5436g, and 13.5435g.
What would these three measurements actually be when applying this uncertainty?

EDIT: Please let it be known that I understand the math and that is not what I am referring to. I was specifically wondering about the semantics since I know balances have uncertainty but was unsure what this specific wording meant.

EDIT2: I have corrected first value

Comment: For broader context, you may want also to search for meanings of terms resolution, precision, trueness, accuracy.

Answer (score 1):

Weighing something to the nearest 0.1 mg is a common wording/terminology in analytical chemistry. In simplest terms, it is an instruction to use a certain type of balance- a balance which can weigh upto 0.1 mg or 0.0001 g. One should *not* round off the values you got if the instruction was to record to the weight to 0.1 mg. Actually, given the variations in your observations about the weight of the same beaker three times, shows the problem of precision of the balance user (oils from fingers, air drift etc.) or balance issues or even electrostatics if the atmosphere were too dry.

Alternatively, another interpretation is that if someone tells you to measure an exact amount of a certain material to a precision of 0.1 mg. This may mean that one has to be *extra* careful during weighing this substance and the variation in your mass should not be +/- 0.1 mg from the suggested amount.

In short the instruction depends on the context.

Comment: this makes sense thank you! this is one of my first analytical chemistry classes and we have not worked very closely with the balances or their uncertainty before. i appreciate you being kind :)

Comment: A dry beaker should show constant mass, or maybe 0.1 mg or 0.2 mg variation when measured with the same analytical balance in sequence. Typical user errors are leaving the doors open when taring, changing the angle of the balance between measurements (by moving the balance or leaning on the table/bench), or working with a balance that is not clean. Oils from fingers are more a 0.01 mg problem.

Answer (score 0):

Your masses are already given to within $\pu{0.1 mg}$. $\pu{0.1 mg}$ is equal to $\pu{0.0001 g}$. You used a balance (I assume) that gives four decimals beyond the decimal point. The difference between - say - $\pu{13.5448 g}$ and $\pu{13.5449 g}$ is in fact $\pu{0.0001 g}$ or $\pu{0.1 mg}$.

Had you dropped the last digit (but there is no reason to do that), your mass would be to within $\pu{1 mg}$. Had you used a scale made for larger masses (like a doctor's scale), the masses might be given to within $\pu{100 g}$. For the small masses in your example, that measurement would be meaningless.

EDIT: corrected values